# OpenPyXl : How can I make the background of a chart transparent?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to make an Exel chart having a transparent background. But I've failed to get my goal. Let me show you my code below.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart.shapes import GraphicalProperties
chart = openpyxl.chart.ScatterChart()
```

------- below all of codes doesn't working :/ ----------

```
chart.graphical_properties.noFill = True
chart.graphicalProperties.noFill = True
chart.plot_area.graphicalProperties(noFill=True)
chart.graphical_properties = GraphicalProperties(noFill=True)
chart.graphicalProperties(noFill=True)
```

---

Please help me T.T

Comment: This will be possible in version 3.1

Answer (score 0):

This work for me for line chart:
In module "Python37\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\chartspace.py" of openpyxl:
-> Modify "class ChartSpace(Serialisable)" at line 185 to "self.spPr = GraphicalProperties(noFill=True)"